# What's the use of 'alt' attribute in the image tag of HTML5?

Tags: html, image, alt-attribute

If the code in HTML5 is:
(*** stands for whatever information we need to fill, it is just for example not a keyword)

```
<img src = "***.jpg" width = "***" height = "**" alt = "*****">
```

Then here what function does the alt attribute actually do?

Answer (score 1):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_alt.asp)

> The required alt attribute specifies an alternate text for an image,
> if the image cannot be displayed.
>
> The alt attribute provides alternative information for an image if a
> user for some reason cannot view it (because of slow connection, an
> error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).